# twitter widget and typekit fonts not loading in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, twitter, typekit

just finishing up my site [www.petersalvato.com](http://www.petersalvato.com)

For some reason the twitter widget and typekit fonts are not loading in firefox but seem fine in most other browsers.

I'm also having type trouble in the nav in older versions of IE.

any help or suggested reading for fixing these issues would be greatly appreciated!

/p

Answer (score 0):

Twitter widget and typekit fonts seems to work on my browser.

The nav in IE7 or less is not surprising.

First of all, for ie6, height = min-height. So you can't constraint the height of an element.

Then the position:relative on ie7 seems to put item in front (making them not partially hidden).

I'd suggest you to add a conditional css for ie6/7.

remove `position:relative` from the `#nav ul li a`.
remove `height:0.5em;` from the `#nav ul li`.

The effect won't be the same as with ie8+/ff/chrome, but it will at least looks *less bad*.